# Explicit automatic migration with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

So I've managed to have some database tables created from my Entity Framework Code First model classes. After changing these model classes and running my code again, I got this exception:

> System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigrationsException: The target context '...Context' is not constructible. Add a default constructor or provide an implementation of IDbContextFactory.

Unfortunately, the database connection parameters are determined at runtime, depending on a user selection. So there is no default or static connection string. A connection can only be established through code logic. Here's one of my numerous hacks I needed to use to make EF work for me:

```
// Manually create database connection because Entity Framework won't let me specify a
// provider name together with a connection string.
// Source: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17403462/143684
var conn = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client").CreateConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = "User Id=" + dbUserName + ";Password=" + dbPassword + ";Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=" + dbHostName + ")(PORT=" + dbPort + "))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=" + dbInstance + ")))";
var appContext = new AppContext(conn);
```

The only constructor for `AppContext` (my `DbContext`) takes a `DbConnection` parameter. A parameterless constructor for `AppContext` won't work because it wouldn't know where to connect to. Yet migrations want one from me.

I call this before the code shown above: (`Configuration` is the code that the PowerShell command generated for me.)

```
Database.SetInitializer(
    new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<AppContext, Configuration>());
```

Can I somehow convince EF to run automatic migrations on the `AppContext` instance I create for it?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try implementing the [IDbContextFactory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh506876(v=vs.113).aspx) interface?

```
public class CustomContextFactory : IDbContextFactory<AppContext>
{
    public AppContext Create()
    {
        return new AppContext(CustomDbConnection);
    }

    private DbConnection CustomDbConnection
    {
        get
        {
            // here goes your code to build a DbConnection
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No, instead I ditched automatic migrations altogether and made my own schema version management with SQL scripts and runtime connection configuration framework. Works fine, doesn't use XML config files at all, and I know exactly how my database looks like.